# kinds of breakfast

Tags: breakfast

For lunch or dinner, there are many types of food one would have. But for breakfast, I cannot think of more than three types:

- Cheese, bread, tea
- Honey or jam, butter, juice
- fruit salad

It'd be nice to know what are types of breakfast one would serve in different cultures or countries.

Suffering from high cholesterol, cannot eat egg much.

Comment: Hey Explorer and welcome to our site.  I think as the question stands right now its a bit more of a survey - which doesn't fit our site well.  It may get closed as such.  If you have a more specific question feel free to ask.

Comment: Maybe try rephrasing. Would "Where can I get more information on the types of foods served by different cultures and countries?" be better? This is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Bacon, sausage, steak...

Oatmeal, Grits, Malt-o-meal

Comment: The most interesting breakfast I've ever had was freshly caught pike with spaghetti, in Russia.

Comment: In Scotland fried fish for breakfast. In USA fried potatoes, eggs, ham, sausages...

Comment: I've voted to close this question. If this question is actually closed, you can reopen it by editing the question. Just as @rfusca indicates, feel free to ask other more specific questions, and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many resources you can find on the types of foods served for breakfast by culture. Wikipedia has the best article I've seen on this topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakfast check it out!

Edit: previously the article was much longer, but it looks like a lot of the stuff has been moved out. Here is a premalink to an older version of that article: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Breakfast&oldid=469968557

Comment: Cool, I'll read this article till the end :-)